# Open connections with Hibernate + Spring + C3P0 + Multithreading

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, c3p0

I have the next abstract configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("my.app")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public abstract class AbstractApplicationConfig {
protected HibernateTransactionManager newHibernateTransactionManager(final LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean) {
    final HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    hibernateTransactionManager.setSessionFactory(localSessionFactoryBean.getObject());
    return hibernateTransactionManager;
}

protected LocalSessionFactoryBean newLocalSessionFactoryBean(final DataSource dataSource, final String packagesToScan) {
    final LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan);
    localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);

    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("databasePlatform"));
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("showSql"));
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 10);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.order_inserts", true);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.order_updates", true);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data", true);

    properties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", 10);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", 50);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout","300");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", 50);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "3000");

    localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
    return localSessionFactoryBean;
}

protected DataSource newDataSource() {
    final ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    try {
        dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getRequiredProperty("dataSource.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("dataSource.url"));
        dataSource.setUser(env.getRequiredProperty("dataSource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("dataSource.password"));
        dataSource.setPreferredTestQuery("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.valueOf(50));
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.valueOf(10));
        dataSource.setMaxStatements(Integer.valueOf(50));
    } catch (final IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final PropertyVetoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataSource;
}
}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SchemaApplicationConfig extends AbstractApplicationConfig {

/** DATASOURCES **/

@Bean
public DataSource dsSchema() {
    final DataSource dataSource = newDataSource(DataSourcesNames.SCHEMA1);
    return dataSource;
}

/** SESIONFACTORIES **/

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sfSchema() {
    final LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = newLocalSessionFactoryBean(dsSchema(), "es.miapp.schema");
    return localSessionFactoryBean;
}

/** TRANSACTIONMANAGERS **/

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager txSchema() {
    final HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager = newHibernateTransactionManager(sfSchema());
    return hibernateTransactionManager;
}
}
```

In my application, I run a process with several Threads:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    AbstractApplicationContext context =  new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SchemaApplicationConfig.class);
    MainProcess mainProcess = context.getBean(MainProcess.class)
    mainProcess.execute();
    context.close();
    System.out.println("ENDS");
}

@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class MainProcessImpl implements MainProcess{

    @Autowired
    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void execute() {
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        final List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            final MyService runnable = (MyService) applicationContext.getBean(MyServiceBean.class);
            final Future<?> future = executorService.submit(runnable);
            futures.add(future);
        }

        for (final Future<?> future : futures) {
            try {
                future.get();
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

MyServiceBean looks like this:

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyServiceBean implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do Stuff and create entity
        myDao.insert(entity);
    }
}
```

And my Dao looks like this:

```
@Repository
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sfSchema")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional("txSchema")
    public void insert(Entity entity) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(entity);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
    }
}
```

The problem here is that Hibernate doesn't close all the connections, and after a  couple of runs of this process, I get the next error:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
```

If I keep executing instances, there is a moment where the program hangs trying to do the insert:

```
[09-08-2018] [11:15:43,961] [DEBUG] [TEST] checkoutStatement: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 18; checked out: 6; num connections: 6; num keys: 18
[09-08-2018] [11:15:43,961] [DEBUG] [TEST] insert into ENTITY... COMPLETE SQL
[09-08-2018] [11:15:43,961] [DEBUG] [TEST] Executing batch size: 1
```

Checking on Oracle, I can see that my user has already 46 connections opened and they keep increasing with every run...

Ideas?

Comment: First your `hibernate.c3p0` are useless as you are injecting an external datasource. Second why is your `min` poolside larger then your `maxpoolsize`? Thirdly where does `applicationContext` come from? Do you recreate it or instantiate it once. Finally instead of C3P0 (dormant for a while) I suggest another, newer and maintained, connection pool like HikariCP.

Comment: The maxpoolsize was a typo, In the real project I read from a properties file, but I wanted to show you the values I'm using. I added the rest of the program too, where you can see how I initialize Spring. Using HikariCP is not an option here, My options are DBCP or C3P0.

Comment: The code here simply won't even compile. How does `MainProcess` get the `ApplicationContext`. That is totally unclear. Also you shouldn't be bound to those datasource implementation as those are basically unmaintained and contain issues. You also have a lot of abstract classes that you extend but it is totally unclear what those do. Make sure you aren't creating additional contexts anywhere or are calling one of those `new*` methods anywhere else, if you do you have an issue.

Comment: I eddited inyecting the ApplicationContext. The original application is really complex, and I don't want to copy everything here, only the important chunks. The abstract classes contains the main login of the project, but internally it doesn't use any Spring Bean that you don't see in this code. I will remove them to clarify it.

Comment: Also define *a couple of runs*? As in executing the `main` method?

Comment: The problem with copying *the important chunks* might not be what the problem is. And what you think could be important couldn't be for the issue at hand.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I know what you mean, and maybe you are right. The program receives a parameter to define which schema to write on (we have 20 schemas / 20 spring configuration files), and another parameter to define which files to read from. Then it launches 5 threads, each one reading a different file and writing the result in the same schema. That's why I don't think the internal functionality might be causing this issue, I see more an issue with how Hibernate or C3P0 is behaving in each thread, and how they release the connection after finishing their tasks.

Comment: c3p0 won't close it it will be returned to the pool and might be discarded if it has been idle too long and the poolside is larger then the minimal size. However your issue clearly with the fact that something is apparently messing around with the `Connection` as well outside the scope you are controlling.

Comment: Seems that you have a connection leak somewhere in your application. Are you sure that the application is really closed? (Check running processes, any java processes still running)